# Import Excel file to Datagridview Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, import-from-excel

Is there a way to display the excel file directly to the Datagridview without the combobox or choosing the sheets to display? Since my excel file contains only 1 sheet.

```
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx"}
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName
        Using stream = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Using reader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                Dim result As DataSet = reader.AsDataSet(New ExcelDataSetConfiguration() With {
                                                             .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration() With {
                                                             .UseHeaderRow = True}})
                tables = result.Tables
                cboSheet.Items.Clear()
                For Each table As DataTable In tables
                    cboSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Using
End Sub



Private Sub cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboSheet.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As DataTable = tables(cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString())
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Well… in the `btnBrowse_Click` event … look at the `result` variable … `result` is a `DataSet` and if there is only one table in that `DataSet`, then you could set that table as a data source to the grid, something like… `DataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables(0)` … I assume I may be missing something.

Comment: It worked well. Thanks.